# how to increase the size of the drive in aws

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-web-services

Could you please let us know how to increase the size of the drive (c drive). This is Windows 2008 server R2. Please let me know the steps to be followed in AWS console to increase the disk size. The X person will initiate AMI, backup & snapshot of a server. After this process he asked us to increase the size of the C drive.

Answer (score 0):

In line of principle it is not possible. You usually need to snapshot and reload the snapshot of the disk, create a new EBS volume (and this depends on the instance type, I consider you are using an instance with EBS, you didn't specify it).

I believe you need to:

1. snapshot the disk
2. create a new EBS of the wanted size
3. load the snapshot of the EBS
4. flip the volume

This is not btw the way I would go.

Honestly I would just allocate a new EBS, attach it to the server and use the existing volume just for the OS.

In this case:

1. Create a new EBS
2. Attach to the EC2 instance
3. Initialize the disk in windows
4. Move the application stack of the files on the EBS
5. Done

I hope this helps somehow